# RecyclerView list Limited at one fragment and no Limit another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

hi I want to make a recycler view in two different fragments in which one fragment has limit recycler view list which is shown only 4 lists and another fragment in which all the list item is shown, thanks in advance.
main class code,

```
private void populatelist() {

    List<reviewModel> reviewModelList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
        int imges = R.drawable.ic_userlogin;
        String names = "User Name is " + i;
        String dates = "New Dates is " + i;
        String detail = "User details about is " + i;

        reviewModel models = new reviewModel(names, dates, detail, 4, imges);

        reviewModelList.add(models);
    }

    setupRecycle(reviewModelList);
}

private void setupRecycle(List<reviewModel> reviewModelList) {

    if (adaptOverView == null)
        adaptOverView = new reviewAdapt(this, 5);

    adaptOverView.setReviewList(reviewModelList);

    LinearLayoutManager layout = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    layout.setSmoothScrollbarEnabled(true);
    recyclerOverView.setLayoutManager(layout);
    recyclerOverView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerOverView.setAdapter(adaptOverView);
}
```

adapter class code,

```
private Context mContext;
private List<reviewModel> reviewList;

private int limit;

public void setReviewList(List<reviewModel> list){
    this.reviewList = list;
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
public reviewAdapt(Context mContext, int limit) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.limit = limit;
}

public reviewAdapt(Context mContext, List<reviewModel> reviewList, int limit) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.reviewList = reviewList;
    this.limit = limit;
}

@NonNull
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.review_design, parent, false);
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        if (position < limit) {
            reviewModel model = reviewList.get(position);

            Log.d("TAG", "onBindViewHolder_Limit: "+limit);
            Log.d("TAG", "onBindViewHolder_Position_Is_InLimit: "+position);
            holder.textViewName.setText(model.getName());
            holder.textViewDate.setText(model.getDate());
            holder.ratingBarRecycle.setRating(model.getRatingBar());
            holder.textViewDetails.setText(model.getDetails());
            holder.imageViewRecycle.setImageResource(model.getImg());
        }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

        return reviewList.size();

}


public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView textViewName, textViewDate, textViewDetails;
    RatingBar ratingBarRecycle;
    ImageView imageViewRecycle;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        textViewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_review);
        textViewDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_review);
        textViewDetails = itemView.findViewById(R.id.details_review);
        ratingBarRecycle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.review_ratingsBar);
        imageViewRecycle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);


    }


}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding , You are using limit variable for restricting listing size for fragment. But you are not using it rightly. If I am not wrong, Try to restrict item count for in adapter as below -

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return limit;
}
```

Comment: if I do this then it will be restricted in both fragment but I want that list restricted in 1 fragment but other fragments will show the full list. that answer I tried but it restricted all places where I use my recycler view.

Comment: This is because you are sending same limit value from different fragments. Try to send limit = 4 for one and limit = list.size for another one

Comment: Make sure list size is not 4 so that you can differentiate in both of cases.

Comment: I don't understand kindly explain it where I set limit =list.size and other sets limit.there is class where i want to set limit about 4 but another fragment class there is no issue about it.

Comment: According to your question, you have two fragments. In one you want to display only 4 items and in second fragment you want to display all the items from the list. Am I right?

Comment: yes, .other list is ok who are full displayed if I use this method in getitem count it restricted other lists also.

Comment: This is happening to you because you are sending same data to the adapter every time, You are not changing your data as per fragments. For fragment 1 you need to send limit value 4 while calling the adapter, and for second one you need to send list.size. or you can simply create an method in adapter to update adapter items as per your requirements.

Comment: If you still have any confusion then share your whole code with me.

Comment: Just share how you are calling adapter from different fragments.

Comment: ok now I understand what are you saying thanks a lot